# insert a list of strings to a table in multiple columns using ibatis

Tags: java, sql, dao, dto, ibatis

I would like to insert a list of strings to a db in multiple rows using ibatis.

```
ie) id = 1
    [a,b,c,d] as list of strings.
```

The table should store the values as

```
 1    a
    1    b
    1    c
    1    d.
```

I can achieve it by repeated use of insert query. Can anybody tell me is this possible with a single query?Any help or pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterate tag of ibatis.

```
 <insert id="" parameterClass="YourClass">
        <iterate property="ListOfStrings">
        INSERT 
            INTO table(colum1,colum2)
            VALUES (#id, #listofStrings[]#)
        </iterate>

    </insert>
```

Try this one:-

```
 <insert id="insert" parameterClass=""> 
  INSERT INTO table 
    (col1, col2) 
  VALUES 
  <iterate property="list" conjunction=","> 
    (#id#, #list[]#) 
  </iterate> 
</insert>
```

Comment: Could you tell me whats the issue now?

Comment: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "iterate" must match "(include|iterate|isParameterPresent|isNotParameterPresent|isEmpty|isNotEmpty|isNotNull|isNull|isNotEqual|isEqual|isGreaterThan|isGreaterEqual|isLessThan|isLessEqual|isPropertyAvailable|isNotPropertyAvailable)".

Comment: Could you verify the version of ibatis you're using, may be your DTD doesn't support iterate?

Comment: i am using ibatis2.7.4